# Permission denied when run python script whnich is trying to open dicom file

Tags: python, windows, permissions, pydicom

I was running a local python flask service to open/analyze the dicom file in windows env
python -V => 3.6.5
pydicom => 1.1.0
...

```
import pydicom
```

but when i run into this line
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(dicom)

the "Permission error"happened
[the premission denied exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdKvk.png)

catched by

```
except BaseException as e:
   print(e)
```

and i tried the [runas cmd] in windows 
[runas wiki in microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))

[run as adminstrator user pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUJl1.png)

[machine name and user rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQa60.png)

but when i called the python service/script again, the same exception happened

[premission denied again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SghDB.png)

the json means i need to access the file path in dicom_list 
`C:\Users\za-chenchen\Desktop\MRA_DICOM`

and i need to analyze the file into jped format
`C:\Users\za-chenchen\Desktop\MRA_DICOM\...\...`

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be trying to open `c:\Users\za-chenchen\Desktop\MRA_DICOM` itself, which is a directory.  Windows does not allow opening a directory as a file and throws a permission error.